# Jinja2 error - [ 'zip' is undefined] How do I iterate through 2 lists at once in Jinja 2?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have 2 separate arraylist which holds user ids and their title respectively. I want to access the list at once and print them in html.
Jinja code:

```
{% for (i,j) in zip(board.users, board.title) %}
      <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-data">{{ i }}</div>
      <div class="table-data">{{ j }}</div>
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When I use the `zip(foo bar)` I get an error - 'zip' is undefined.
How is it possible in jinja2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` is not part of the Jinja2 global namespace. You can add it, though:

```
from jinja2 import Environment
env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader("yourapp"),
    autoescape=select_autoescape()
)
env.globals.update(zip=zip)
```

Alternatively, if you only want `zip` available for a single template, you can extend the environment globals for that template using [`get_template`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#jinja2.Environment.get_template).